# Перестала работать передача данных по протоколу UDP

Tags: java, udp

Есть два простеньких приложения, написаны на Java осуществляющие передачу данных по протоколу UDP между двумя компьютерами (PC1 и PC2).
Код немного сократил, для наглядности.

PC1 - отправляет данные

```
private final static String IP_ADDR = "224.1.1.201";
DatagramSocket socket;
public void sending() {
    socket = new DatagramSocket();
    group = InetAddress.getByName(IP_ADDR);
    sendingDataBuffer = parserData(dataBuffer);
    DatagramPacket packet 
    = new DatagramPacket(sendingDataBuffer, sendingDataBuffer.length, group, SERVICE_PORT);
    socket.send(packet);
}
```

PC2 - принимает данные

```
private final static String IP_ADDR = "224.1.1.201";
MulticastSocket socket;
public void received() {
    socket = new MulticastSocket(SERVICE_PORT);
    InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(IP_ADDR);
    socket.joinGroup(group);
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(receivingDataBuffer, receivingDataBuffer.length);
    socket.receive(packet);             
}
```

Все когда-то работало, код не менялся. Запускаю сейчас и на приемной стороне тишина. Если запустить эти приложения на одном хосте, например PC1, то все работает.
Не пойму в чем может быть проблема? Может администраторы изменили сетевые настройки и это как-то повлияло. Может они что-то заблокировали, но они в этом сами не признаются.
Но как можно проверить где проблема? Как ее обнаружить?
Ping PC2 со стороны PC1 проходит нормально.
IP_ADDR - это не адрес ip, адрес группы.

Запустил wireshark, добавил фильтр

```
udp.port in {51491}
```

И wireshark ни чего не показывает на этом порту. Не пойму почему? Локально же обмен идет.
А на этом порту ни чего нет в wireshark , даже когда оба приложения запускаю на одном хосте и когда обмен между ними работает.

Может у кого то есть рабочий пример обмена данными по UDP в режиме Multicast?

Comment: Используйте утилиты tcpdump/wireshark и сравнивайте ситуацию, когда все работает и не работает. Будет разница в посланных и полученных пакетах и на основании этого, можно понять, где и что не проходит. Еще бы знать как у вас устроена сеть, т.е. в одной ли подсети компьютеры, если нет, то что между ними и т.д.

Comment: А у Java нет возможности просмотра того, что уходит в сеть и что приходит? У нас тут запрещено ставить любое стороннее ПО.

Comment: То что можно увидеть на уровне java, вам не поможет, это из вашего кода и так видно. Нужно смотреть на уровне пакетов, проблема там.

Comment: Может быть, но как это обнаружить с помощью wireshark? Куда смотреть? Я с ним первый раз столкнулся

Comment: не могу, у меня прав нет на это

Comment: Проблема оказалась в том, что передающая сторона отправляла пакеты в сеть virtualBox, поэтому я их и не видел в Wireshark. С приемной стороной та же беда была, она тоже читала из сети virtualBox. Вот как мен в Java указать в какую сеть слать пакеты? Или это тема нового вопроса?